# Shopify `image_url` filter generating incorrect image URL

Tags: image, shopify, height, width, crop

I'm working on a Shopify theme in a development store.

For some reason, the following liquid does not seem to work as intended:

```
{{- product.featured_image | image_url: width: 500, height: 500, crop: 'center' | image_tag: loading: 'lazy' -}}
```

The end result is something like this:

```
<img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0549/6229/0788/products/untitled.jpg?crop=center&height=500&v=1665271372&width=500" alt="falling moon" srcset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0549/6229/0788/products/untitled.jpg?crop=center&height=500&v=1665271372&width=352 352w" width="500" height="500" loading="lazy">
```

As you can see, the `width` query parameter is being appended right at the very end of the images URL, after the cache-busting `v` query parameter.  It is supposed to come before the `v` param.

If you alter the URL manually, updating it to something like `untitled.jpg?crop=center&width=500&height=500&v=1665271372`, things work as expected and you get the image with the width, height and crop you have specified.

At the moment, I can only seem to pass either `width` *or* `height` along with `crop`. The behaviour then seems to change a little, more a resize (to the width or height you have set) than an actual crop.

None of this is documented and I can't find any mention of this online.

Has anyone had this issue before? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`image_url` and `image_tag` are the new filters.
With the deprecated ones I get a better result, not sure if that helps.

```
    {{ product.featured_image | img_url: '500x500', crop: 'center' | img_tag: loading: 'lazy' }}
```